# Python beatutiful soup 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to grab some links fra a website and write them to a file after they've been cleaned up. The links on the site looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr01-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr01_0@147054/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 20);">DR1</a><br>
<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr02-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr02_0@147055/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 21);">DR2</a><br>
<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr03-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr03_0@147056/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 701);">DR3</a><br>
<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr06-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr06_0@147059/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 31);">DR Ultra</a><br>
<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr04-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr04_0@147057/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 38);">DR K</a><br>
<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr05-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr05_0@147058/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 50);">DR Ramasjang</a><br>
```

and I can grab them using this:

```
links = soup.findAll(href=re.compile("javascript"))
```

giving me this output:

```
[<a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr01-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr01_0@147054/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 20);">DR1</a>, <a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr02-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr02_0@147055/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 21);">DR2</a>, <a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr03-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr03_0@147056/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 701);">DR3</a>, <a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr06-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr06_0@147059/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 31);">DR Ultra</a>, <a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr04-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr04_0@147057/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 38);">DR K</a>, <a href="javascript:changeChannel('http://dr05-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dr05_0@147058/index_1700_av-b.m3u8', 50);">DR Ramasjang</a>]
```

Now I want to clean this up so I only get the http:// part theres between the '' and this is where it goes bad.

I've tried with

```
fullink = links.get('href')
```

where I get the error:

```
'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get'
```

So how do I get the links out of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Beautiful Soup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous) says:

> AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'foo' - This
>   usually happens because you expected find_all() to return a single tag
>   or string. But find_all() returns a *list* of tags and strings–a
>   ResultSet object. You need to iterate over the list and look at the
>   .foo of each one. Or, if you really only want one result, you need to
>   use find() instead of find_all().

So you probably want `full_links = [x.get("href") for x in links]` .

Comment: With this i got rid of the <a href= part and name of the link but i still have the javascript:changechannel. I only need the http links.
I then tried with fullink.split("'")[1]
but again i get an error 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: you could use `[a['href'] for a in links]` because all selected `links` has `href` attribute.

Comment: @user3332151: try: `links = re.findall("'([^']+)'", "\n".join([a['href'] for a in javascript_links]))`

Comment: Tried the above and got: fullink = re.findall("'([^']+)'", "\n".join([a['href'] for a in links]))
TypeError: string indices must be integers