# Calling more than one function in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

**Problem Definition**

I've some problem working with BeautifulSoup module (bs4). I need to parse some CSS class's (findAll()) string and unwrapping (or you can say removing all tags from soup) them using get_text() function but there are some misunderstanding points. I want to make a soup

```
page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.example.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
data = soup.findAll("a", { "class": "example_class" }
```

and soup shows the html code for specified url.

```
<a href="/en/link/sth.asp?id=4786" class="example_class">This is the data which I want to access and shows only.
```

and later I want to convert data variable to *This is the data which I want to access and shows only.* form. Later, my IDE said that you don't access the data using

```
data.get_text()
```

in this way. Because *soup* instance have some functions but *data* have not. Then, I preperad another soup which input comes from *data* but interestingly, I got an error like below.

```
another_soup = soup.getText(data)
```

**Error**

Error which comes from usage of BeautifulSoup

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 586, in getText
return separator.join(strings)
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'join'
```

**Personal Opinion**

I think my problem related with incorrect usage or access with BeautifulSoup's *soup* instance. What do you suggest for calling two function for a *soup* instance? Calling two times with same instance proper way or creating different instances (which I did above)

**Related Questions Which I Found Before I Ask This Question**

[Python beatutiful soup 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531313/python-beatutiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-get)

[Python/BeautifulSoup - how to remove all tags from an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206380/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-remove-all-tags-from-an-element)

Comment: findAll returns a python  list, what are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll()` returns a `list` of `BeautifulSoup.Tag` objects. You have to iterate over this list and call the `get_text()` function on each item to remove tags.

```
page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.example.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

data = soup.findAll("a", { "class": "example_class" }
data = [link.get_text() for link in data]
```